# Box2d part of softbody passing through walls

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I am trying to get a softbody to behave like jelly. The softbody is made up of a circle shape in the center and 12 smaller circles along the radius. All the radial circles are connected to the center and to their adjacent circles. Picked this from here [softbody box2d](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y9OnUdG12B8).

To get the effect of jelly sticking, I create a distance joint whenever a radial body collides with the shape. This works well and the body looks like its sticking.

The problem I have is that since the radial circles and the center circle are joined by an elastic distance joint, the radial circle is sometimes passing through solid walls.The body goes from [image: sticking] to [image: passing through walls]  when the body is moved against the wall.

I have tried increasing the velocity,position iterations and calling step even 360 times per second but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe add a max length for the joint?

Comment: making the distance joint with collideConnected set to true solved the problem for me.
thanks